# Trying to launch the bot but nothing happens discord.js

Tags: npm, discord, discord.js

So I tried to start with npm start my discord.js bot today, I already have set up the npm start script and nothing went wrong, the problem is that nothing happens after my command, I looked if other had the same problem and tried their solution but I still have this problem. After some time I decided to console.log my client object in the global scope and it worked, but everything else that is in my client.on("ready", () => { ...code...} methode wont be executed, do you guys have an idea what is wrong here?

Commands won't work because my bot is shown offline in discord

Answer (score -1):

Well, I just found the solution to my question, I dunno if I placed "client.login(config.token);" inside the "ready" event before I went to sleep a bit but this was the problem, The bot could'nt start because the client.login() methode was inside the "ready" event which contradicts with the login methode...

Comment: Glad to hear that you found a solution! Next time, make sure that you are carefully choosing your words as the request you made was confusing, also make sure to provide the whole code so we can see the issue more clear.